# Information is not returned while fetching it from MySQL using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am following the [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) tutorial from W3 schools. While mostly everything works fine, it doesn't seem to be returning any of the actual information from the MySQL database I made, called `exercises` in the `exercisedb` database.

Below is the code for `index.php`

```
    <head>
    <title>
        Database Fetch Demo
    </title>
<script>
function showExercise(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtPlaceholder").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtPlaceholder").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getexercise.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <select name="exercises" onchange="showExercise(this.value)">
        <option value="">Choose an Exercise</option>
        <option value="1">Bench Press</option>
        <option value="2">Deadlift</option>
        <option value="3">Barbell Squat</option>
    </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtPlaceholder">
    <b>No exercise selected.</b>
</div>
<body>
</html>
```

And below is the code for `getexercise.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table td, td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    th {text-align: left};
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','exercisedb');
if(!$connect){
    die('Could not connect ' . mysqli_error($connect));
}

mysqli_select_db($connect, "exercisedb");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE id = '".q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Exercise Name</th>
<th>Difficulty</th>
<th>Target Areas</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['difficulty'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['targetareas'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any error messages being generated, either in your JS, in the DB, or on the server? What are you receiving from your AJAX call?

Comment: What basic debugging have you done? Have you checked your browser console? Have you gone directly to `getexercise.php?q=1` to check if your php code works? Do you even know if this is a javascript or php issue?

Comment: You have `q` instead of `$q` in `$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE id = '".q."'";`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I improved the title and wording of the question for better readability. Please add any errors you receive as mentioned by @wolffer-east  check your JavaScript, database and server for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should not send a

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<body>
```

in your ajax answer only the content of the div you expect.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, but is indeed something the OP should be aware of.